# Yii2 using pretty url returns 404

Tags: php, apache, yii2

I've set up a few Yii projects and never had this problem. I'm using the basic template.

**`Apache config`**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName shop
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/web"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/web">
 RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# if $showScriptName is false in UrlManager, do not allow accessing URLs with script name
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]

# ...other settings...
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

URL manager **`app/config/web.php`**:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'rules' => [

     ],
],
```

Whats weird is that it lets me access `shop/gii` and `shop/product` but if I try to navigate anywhere else I get a

> Error: 404 object not found.

If I remove the `UrlManager` config everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]
```

That is what is making the problem and not allowing you to access the routes, i normally use the following config and never had any problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.virtualdomain.local
       DocumentRoot "F:\xampp\htdocs\someproject\frontend\web"

       <Directory "F:\xampp\htdocs\someproject\frontend\web">
           # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
           RewriteEngine on
           # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
           RewriteRule . index.php

           # use index.php as index file
           DirectoryIndex index.php

           # ...other settings...
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you - looking at it now this is the same as I have on my work pc. Started a project today at home and had to set up apache + vhost and took that config straight from the Yii2 site should probably notify them

Comment: yeah you can add the issue on github, they would add the fix for it but i think it could be solved by adding a `/` before `index.php/` like this `RewriteRule ^/index.php/ - [L,R=404]` @Kyle